# Remove "?" from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas dataset which has columns and it's Dtype is object. The columns however has numerical float values inside it along with '?' and I'm trying to convert it to float. I want to remove these '?' from the entire column and making those values Nan but not 0 and then convert the column to float64.

The output of value_count() of Voltage column look like this :

```
?         3771
240.67     363
240.48     356
240.74     356
240.62     356
          ... 
227.61       1
227.01       1
226.36       1
227.28       1
227.02       1
Name: Voltage, Length: 2276, dtype: int64
```

What is the best way to do that in case I've entire dataset which has "?" inside them along with numbers and i want to convert them all at once.

I tried something like this but it's not working. I want to do this operation for all the columns. Thanks

```
df['Voltage'] = df['Voltage'].apply(lambda x: float(x.split()[0].replace('?', '')))
```

1 More question. How can I get "?" from all the columns. I tried something like. Thanks

```
    list = []
for i in df.columns:
    if '?' in df[i]
    continue
    series = df[i].value_counts()['?']
    list.append(series)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what the data look like?

Comment: Do you want to remove the `?` characters and completely ignore them or turn the entire column into `NaN`?

Comment: Please, post only one question per message. So, no "1 more question": ask a separate question.

Comment: @StonedTensor I've updated the main post. Please check

Comment: @Brhaka I want to remove those "?" and make that column entry as Nan so that later on I can fill those Nan values with some other values.

Comment: Your example is more than weird. First, type is `int64`. So there can't be any `?` (nor any NaN) in `Voltage`. Plus, the value in `Voltage` doesn't look like a voltage. But the index does (it looks like typical voltage in a 230/240V country, with some uncertain undervoltage. And your index contains one `?`.

Comment: @chrslg I checked using df.info() and it's indeed showing 'object' for voltage and some other columns. I even tried to find the mean df['Voltage'].mean but it's showing error for the same reasons. And above is the output of df['Voltage'].value_counts() I hope I'm clear. Thanks

Comment: But that changes everything! We can't guess that, and we can't investigate like Sherlock to try to understand how your data are. Please, try not to conceal important information that prevent us to help you!

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that. I've updated the main post. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from your `value_count`, it is clear, that you just have some values that are floats, in a string, and some values that contain `?` (apparently that ARE `?`).

So, the one thing NOT to do, is use `apply` or `applymap`.
Those are just one step below `for` loops and `iterrows` in the hierarchy of what not to do.
The only cases where you should use `apply` is when, otherwise, you would have to iterate rows with `for`. And those cases almost never happen (in my real life, I've used apply only once. And that was when I was a beginner, and I am pretty sure that if I were to review that code now, I would find another way).

In your case

```py
df.Voltage = df.Voltage.where(~df.Voltage.str.contains('\?')).astype(float)
```

should do what you want

`df.Voltage.str.contains('\?')` is a True/False series saying if a row contains a `'?'`. So `~df.Voltage.str.contains('\?')` is the opposite (True if the row does not contain a `'\?'`. So `df.Voltage.where(~df.Voltage.str.contains('\?'))` is a serie where values that match `~df.Voltage.str.contains('\?')` are left as is, and the other are replaced by the 2nd argument, or, if there is no 2nd argument (which is our case) by `NaN`. So exactly what you want. Adding `.astype(float)` convert everyhting to float, since it should now be possible (all rows contains either strings representing a float such as `230.18`, or a NaN. So, all convertible to float).

An alternative, closer to what you where trying, that is replacing first, in place, the `?`, would be

```py
df.loc[df.Voltage=='?', 'Voltage']=None
# And then, df.Voltage.astype(float) converts to float, with NaN where you put None
```

Comment: Great answer! I was trying to answer this question using applymap. Good to know I should never be using that method.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. How can I do this for every columns like using a loop or something so I don't have to repeat this for every columns.